# When the following expected value is finite?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Let us consider the stochastic process $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ that can be described by the following SDE:
$$
dX_t = \alpha(X_t, t) dt + \sigma(X_t, t) dB_t
$$

Now I consider the following expected value:
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{-\int_t^T X_s ds}].
$$
My question is:

What conditions should be fulfilled by the functions $\alpha(x,t)$ and $\sigma(x,t)$ to make the above expectation finite?

Intuitively, I think that boundedness of $\sigma(x, t)$ for negative $x$ is enough ensure finiteness of the above expected value, however I do not know how to prove it formally or even strengthen (or weaken) this condition.

Comment: 1. What exactly do you mean by a "bounded expectation"? Do you mean "finite expectation"? Or do you want to some boundedness w.r.t $T$..? 2. Do you have a specific application in mind? I would rather doubt that there are conditions which apply in this generality.

Comment: I mean finite expectation.I do not have any specific application in mind, but I remember that I read somewhere that if the process can take negative values and moreover $\sigma(x, t)$ is not bounded for negative x, then this expectation I mentioned in the main post is not finite.